# Scribus book templates

Tags: book, scribus

I'm preparing a textbook; mostly text, with some illustrations, and I'm considering Scribus. Does anyone have any suggestions on using Scribus for book-length material, or know where can I find appropriate templates?

Comment: How did you go? I am in a similar position right now and wanting to see how you fared.

Comment: Yes, an update would be great! I gave Scribus a spin a few years ago. And while I was impressed for open source software, it had just enough bugs in it that I don't know if I'd trust it to book-length documents.

Comment: No news yet, sorry; working on other projects.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is really going to be opinion-based and encourage link-only answers.

Answer (score 3):

Scribus is a high quality desktop publishing program, you are going in the right direction by choosing Scribus over any other open source solution or regular word processor. if you want to find resources like templates and scripts go to <del>http://scribusstuff.org</del>

The link is no longer available. You can see the site through archive.org here (although the downloadable resources aren't available to download):
https://web.archive.org/web/20160602015018/http://scribusstuff.org/